# Is there a Linux From Scratch (LFS) ARM equivalent

Tags: operating-systems, cross-compilation, tutorial

I'd like to demonstrate how it's possible to 'bootstrap' up from a near-bare installation of Linux to something useful and productive. [The Tiny Core](http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/) and [LFS](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) projects demonstrate this well. However they are specific images for x86 based systems

Is there a similar project based around ARM based systems, and specifically the Raspberry Pi. If not how would one bootstrap a similar project. It would need to take into account the limited memory, storage and processor speed available and the non-free blob requirements, but should still be possible to build a small custom system.

Bonus points if compilation could be done on a separate host via cross-compiling, or using something like dist-cc over a bunch of Pis.

Comment: Is there something wrong with Arch Linux? That's a pretty bare bones distro.

Comment: I don't really want a distro as such, but illustrate doing it all from scratch as an educational tool. So rather than installing a bare Arch and doing "pacman install foo bar baz" (or whatever the command is) I want to show getting the source for something, building it manually. Much like LFS and Tiny Core does.

Comment: +1 for the interesting question then. Would make an excellent learning exercise.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes. There is a [CLFS for ARM](http://cross-lfs.org/view/clfs-embedded/arm/) manual available. Don't be worried by the CLFS name, that is what [Linux From Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/) calls the manual for compiling LFS on non-x86 systems.

> Cross Linux From Scratch provides the means to cross-compile an LFS system on many types of systems.

Answer (score 16):

I just started a site dedicated to Linux From Scratch on the Raspberry Pi:

http://www.intestinate.com/pilfs

Enjoy!

Answer (score 7):

There is also a "[The Tiny Core](http://forum.tinycorelinux.net/index.php?topic=13982.0)" for Raspberry Pi

And here is the [link to the image](http://distro.ibiblio.org/tinycorelinux/4.x/armv6/)

Answer (score 2):

Look at ttylinux: http://ttylinux.net/
There is a small distribution for BeagleBone, and the entire build system is in GitHub.