# How can I install Debian from scratch?

Tags: debian, operating-systems

I would like to install a plain Debian operating system on my pi without all the software and config that comes with the Raspbian image.

Is there a guide for this?

Comment: According to the [Raspbian FAQ](http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianFAQ#What_is_Raspbian.3F), Raspbian is "just" an unofficial optimized Debian port for ARMv6 CPUs. I know that some additional softwares (such as `raspi-config` or `omxplayer`) come with the distro, but it is only to help the user.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to share his/her thoughts on why this was a bad question? I can't see any obvious breaches of this: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask

Answer (score 1):

You will need some of the boot magic and a kernel that work on the board. These don't come with mainline Debian. You might be able to install these on a fresh card from some source (anyone have instructions?) or you might use a ready SD card image, but wipe the root partition to leave just the booting bits.

Then you might be able to use that kernel and a [Debian install initrd](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/debian-installer/) (maybe [netboot versatile](http://ftp.nl.debian.org/debian/dists/squeeze/main/installer-armel/current/images/versatile/netboot/)?) to boot into the installer. I did this while [installing debian on an NSA310](https://sites.google.com/site/realblades/misc/debian-on-zyxel-nsa310) and it works if the kernel is adequate and you can manage the boot process. You might also look at the [Raspbian installer kit](http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianInstaller).

Alternatively, you could use a second machine with a card reader and use [debootstrap](http://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap). If that ends up being cross install (e.g. amd64 installing for armel), you might need [a few tricks](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RootfsFromScratch/QemuDebootstrap). There should be several documents around describing debootstrap for arm boards. This I've only tried on i386, but will probably try for arm in the future.

Comment: May also be of interest:  http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/25/is-there-a-linux-from-scratch-lfs-arm-equivalent