# LFS on ARM with Blink

Tags: archlinux, linux, operating-systems, kernel, software-development

I am interested in creating a LFS (Linux From Scratch distro) on ARM with a HTML5 rendering layer, like how Mozilla's Firefox OS has. However, I want to use the new Blink rendering engine powering Chrome and Opera (soon) instead of Gecko. I've been playing around with my RasPis so I know how to get a prepackaged OS up and running, but I want to do my own thing.

[I have a few mockups](http://dribbble.com/nokadota/projects/127021-hikari-OS) at the moment in case you want to see what I'm aiming for. Just how feasible is this project?

(I was looking into using Qt, and then LFS. I then stumbled across [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/25/is-there-a-linux-from-scratch-lfs-arm-equivalent), which answered another question I had.)

EDIT: [This question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4057/how-can-i-boot-directly-into-google-chrome-web-browser), (how to boot into a browser instance) is close to the mine, if I wanted a simpler implementation. I also want to use a browser and a browser inside a browser means iframes, which some sites do not like. Google.com, for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a very cool project, but I don't think you actually want a browser in a browser. I think you want something like [Coherent](http://coherent-labs.com/overview/), which essentially lets you construct an HTML5 user interface. (In which you can embed a proper browser window as part of it's framework... I think.) The problem with this is that Coherent's not free, open-source, and probably doesn't support ARM or OpenGL ES. But I think it's the sort of thing you'd need to create the user experience your mock-ups suggest.

You might be able to instead of using frames, as part of a UI toolkit have multiple browser instances, sort of like tiling windows in a window manager. I think Qt might let you do it. In that scenario something like a full screen application with a few browser instances inside of it. This is really quite speculative on my part.

Overall thoughts: very cool project, probably doable, but very tricky.

Comment: Thanks for the info Fred, I now have a direction to go towards once I get further along in development. If anyone is interested, here's my project on GitHub: https://github.com/IdeasNeverCease/hikari.